# Yahoo not receiving email CodeIgniter PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am facing an issue. whenever I type Gmail account for registration I received email from php but when i type yahoo account for form registration my email sent but didn't received it in yahoo.
here is my helper code.

```
 function SendMailRegister($to, $subject,$message,$from_email='thing@some.com'){    
    
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com', //
        'smtp_port' => 465,        
        'smtp_user' => SMTP_USER, //
        'smtp_pass' => SMTP_PASSWORD, //
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE        
    );   
    
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('email', $config);    
    $CI->email->set_mailtype("html");
    $CI->email->from($from_email,'Navafiz Support');
    $CI->email->reply_to($from_email);            
    $CI->email->to($to);
    $CI->email->subject($subject);
    $CI->email->message($message);                
    if($CI->email->send())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        //echo $CI->email->print_debugger();        
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sikandar, Did you check your Bulk Mail folder of receiver account? Sometimes the mail sent from third party application is considered as spam message.

Comment: @MonayemIslam yes its empty